# Staking contract where APY depends on user pariticipation in pool

Tags: contract-development, defi, staking, liquid-staking

I'm trying to build a staking contract. The contract has following constarints:

- the APY from the staking pool will depend on users participation. i.e, more users, less rewards.
- The total awards to be distributed among the user will be fixed i.e, a MAX_REWARD cap.

Not sure how to do this. Are there any protocols doing this ?

Edit:
There is a expiry time for the contract and MAX_REWARD is cap that enforces the contract to only mint that amount of reward for it's lifetime/expiry.
If the MAX_REWARD cap is 10 ethers and expiry is 2 months. Only 10 ethers will be distributed among the participants during staking period of 2 months.

Comment: The question is too "open". Each step seems doable individually, but together doesn't. Fixed reward and dependent on user participation are contradictory.

Comment: Have added a edit to the existing question for clarification. @Ismael